# Flutter: How to open (view) office (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf, and etc.) local files using WebView on windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, webview, desktop

I tried the webview_windows package, but if I open a file by url like this:
`file:///D:/test.docx`, the file is beginning download.

I used this code:

```
_controller.loadUrl('file:///D:/test.docx');

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Webview(
    _controller,
    permissionRequested: _onPermissionRequested,
  );
}
```

from this [example](https://github.com/jnschulze/flutter-webview-windows/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart).